# How can add parameters to href url when click on tag a?

Tags: javascript

I want  From  `home` page send parameter `id` to `carts` page:

This is current code, but it not woking:

```
<a  href="carts" onclick="addParam();">detail</a>
<script>

     function addParam()
     {
         var url = window.location.href;
         var listId = localStorage.getItem('IDs', '');          
         url=url+ "?id=" +listId;
         window.location.href = url;
     }
</script>
```

How can add parameters to href url when click on tag a?

Comment: `onclick="addParam(this);"` and `function addParam(elem)
     {
         elem.href = url;
     }`

Comment: Ok, thank you. it had working.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either just override it by grabbing the element's (here done by passing `this` to the function) `href`

```
<a  href="carts" onclick="addParam(this);">detail</a>
<script>

     function addParam(el)
     {
         var listId = localStorage.getItem('IDs', '');          
         window.location.href = el.href + "?id=" +listId;
     }
</script>
```

Or append it to the element's `href`

```
<a  href="carts" onclick="addParam(this);">detail</a>
<script>

     function addParam(el)
     {
         var listId = localStorage.getItem('IDs', '');          
         el.href += "?id=" +listId;
     }
</script>
```